# CDATA tag getting wrapped in and commented

Tags: xslt, xhtml

I am working on translating a XHTML to another XHTML(for localization) the tool we can use is XSLT alone that is a restriction. Now when I am trying to copy the whole code as is for testing purpose the CDATA values of original XHTML are lost. I used below tag cdata-section-elements="script" but, it is commenting whole CDATA and it is resulting in loosing format of my original XHTML

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:output method="html" cdata-section-elements="script"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"/>
<xsl:template match="div[@id='HEADER']">
    <div id="HEADER">
        <p>This is the <em>improved</em> header.</p>
    </div>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="script|style">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('//&lt;![CDATA[&#xA;',text(),'&#xA;//]]&gt;')" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*|@*" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show a sample of your input XML please, as well as the output you expect? Thank you!

Comment: CDATA isn't part of the XDM data model, so the XSLT stylesheet will never know whether input data was wrapped in CDATA or not. You should be able to generate CDATA in the serialized output, but the combination of cdata-section-elements and disable-output-escaping seems a little odd.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue as you mentioned Michael Kay  the disable-output-escaping and the cdata tag were a odd combination. I kind of added CDATA tags as text in XSLT and that worked. I have worked on XML, XSLT and XSD only and never dealt with this situation so, I was not aware that this combi doesn't go well... Thanks everyone for responses